# Nested modules with Spring

Tags: java, spring

I am developing project with Spring Framework.
I have created about 5 modules, sometimes one depend on other, but they are all on top level, and up to this point everything works fine.

Example:

Database module has only external dependencies

Identity module depends on database module

Facebook stuff module depends on identity module

Now, I have created directory in root of project called modules, and moved all modules into it (so they all were, and still are on same relative distance to each other).

All tests passes and I can build/compile and inspect classes without any problem.

However, now when I try to run only identity module (that does not require  facebook stuff) spring throws me an exception, that it cannot find facebook beans. Of course it cannot, because there is no dependency, but I do not want to add this dependency. @Configuration is @Lazy so there is no point creating such @Bean anyway.

**Code:**

```
new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Application.class);
```

Application class is @Lazy @Configuration and does @ComponentScan from whole application, and as I understand it finds also @Configuration's from other modules and then - I do not know why - tried to create those @Bean's from other modules but fails as expected.

I have verified with git, that the only between working and not working states are moving those modules into new folder.

So to clarify, working/default structure is:

```
/.gradle

/.idea

/DatabaseModule

/IdentityModule

/FacebookModule

/.out

/.gitignore
```

and not working one is:

```
/.gradle

/.idea

/modules/DatabaseModule

/modules/IdentityModule

/modules/FacebookModule

/.out

/.gitignore
```

Code stays the same.

I think, that if I will add all dependencies to all modules then it will work but for obvious reasons I do not want to do this.

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there any convention, that I am breaking?

Bonus question: how are nested modules different, from ordinary folder containing modules?

EDIT:
I should also note, that all tests pass in both scenarios, however I am not using spring in tests (no dependency injection) - just new or Mock() everything

Comment: how do you plan to let know spring that running module has which dependency or has no dependency ?

Comment: I am packing compiled output from modules to JAR. Spring is free to use any and all Configuration's and Component's that it will find, because database simply won't have compiled output from facebook stuff. However, given same JAR configuration, problem persists.

Comment: Spring scans components from packages at compile time and registers them, so you have to exclude these modules before spring's annotation processing start.

Comment: Also one more thing, this packing compiled output requires a definition of Which module has dependency or hasn't,  so if you are doing this instead you can create different spring contexts for per module

Comment: I declare dependencies through gradle, and a I said, "database" does not have any dependency to "facebook stuff" not by gradle and not by compile output into jar. I have checked those two places. Problem is that database module is still somehow aware of facebook stuff on compile time (that is wrong), but is unaware (cannot find it) at runtime (this is okay).

Comment: Yes, I have tried of doing for example "identity" to have own context that included parent context of "database" plus it's own configuration - no difference.